# Autofac MVC Integration with ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: autofac, asp.net-mvc-4

I am starting a new project in ASP.Net MVC 4 and I was wondering if it was possible to use Autofac MVC3 Integration with a MVC 4 project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, grab the NuGet package and go for it :)

Answer (score 5):

There is now an MVC4 package on NuGet:
https://nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc4/

More info: [Autofac ASP.NET MVC 4 (Beta) Integration](http://alexmg.com/post/2012/03/09/Autofac-ASPNET-MVC-4-%28Beta%29-Integration.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Replaced Unity.Mvc with Autofac due to intermittent issues with Unity.Mvc. I did this replacement just this morning.

Project is an MVC 4 project and I am using the Autofac Mvc 4 beta. Works like a charm, and really like the auto registration feature (lacking in Unity).

Two thumbs up!!